# Understand certain way of proving binomial series for $|x|<1$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, exponentiation, binomial-theorem

I'm trying to understand a certain way of proving that

$$(1+x)^\alpha =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{n}x^n$$

for $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$ and  $|x|<1$.

Now, my notes tackle that proof by saying that for $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{n}z^n \cdot \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{\beta}{n}z^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nz^n$$

with $$c_n =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{\alpha}{k}\binom{\beta}{n-k}=\binom{\alpha + \beta}{n} $$

and proceeding by proving that by induction.

Now, I can't even understand why proving the second notion would prove the initial theorem, so if anybody could explain or provide further material since I can't find anything about that particular way of proof, I'd be very thankful.

Comment: I suppose that, when you wrote $(1+x)^\alpha=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n}{k}x^n$, what you meant was $(1+x)^\alpha=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom\alpha nx^n$.

Comment: Note your original series should have $\binom{\alpha}{n}$ instead of $\binom{n}{k}$. The indices in your other series are also highly suspect.

Comment: $f_a(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {a \choose n}x^n$ from your formula you have $f_{ma}(x) f_a(x) = f_{(m+1)a}(x)$ and this is what you need to obtain $f_{u/v}(x)^v = f_u(x) = (1+x)^u$ (where $u,v\in \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$ so that $f_u(x) = (1+x)^u$ is easy to show)

Comment: Sorry, just realized that I had mistakes in my notes, changed them to fit the original script.

Comment: This is one of lesser known proofs of binomial theorem. The proof with all details is available in my post: https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2016/07/the-general-binomial-theorem-part-2.html?m=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that what you wrote on the second paragraph is *not* meant to be a proof of the fact that $$(1+x)^\alpha=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom\alpha nx^n,\tag1$$but a proof of the fact that, if you *define* $(1+x)^\alpha$ by $(1)$, then$$(1+x)^\alpha(1+x)^\beta=(1+x)^{\alpha+\beta},\tag2$$since what it says there is precisely what is needed to prove that $(2)$ holds.

Comment: I have just edited the question to match the original script, thanks for pointing out the mistakes. And you're right, (2) is there to prove a property that is later used to prove that $\alpha$ can be rational.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate proof, if you're interested.

One may show that 
$$p_n(\alpha)=\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}x^\alpha\right]_{x=1}=\prod_{r=1}^{n}(\alpha-r+1).$$
So then the Taylor series for $x^\alpha$ about $x=1$ is given by
$$x^\alpha=\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{p_k(\alpha)}{k!}(x-1)^k.$$
We notice that 
$${n\choose k}=\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{n+1-i}{i}.$$
So we have 
$$(1+x)^\alpha=\sum_{k\ge0}{\alpha\choose k}x^k.$$